# Selectquery with where conditiion

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT * FROM ".TB_TAMIL_PRODUCTMASTER." WHERE Name='இந்தியாRajan'"
```

This query exist but in display

```
SELECT * FROM TamilProductMaster WHERE Name='???????Rajan'.
```

Using following query `"SELECT * FROM ".TB_TAMIL_PRODUCTMASTER` will display the following output.

```
இந்தியா நாட்டின் பக்கங்கள்
இந்தியா
Rajan
இந்தியாRajan
```

this four columns in `TamilProductMaster`.

How to where condition specify in Tamil string characters

INSERT INTO tamilproductmaster (Code, Name) VALUES ('8', 'தமிழ் ௭ழுத்துகள்') this query work perfectly in phpmyadmin .

But php file it is display only this format 
$Insertquery = "INSERT INTO tamilproductmaster (Code, Name) VALUES ('8', '??????? ???????? ?????????5')";

Comment: encode to utf-8 and it will work ;)

Comment: how to encode to utf-8 format in php file.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ".TB_TAMIL_PRODUCTMASTER." WHERE Name='இந்தியாRajan'" this query is work in phpmyadmin but not in php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=NULL");
```

Comment: I am using mysqli method for insert and select query

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov is right, StackOverflow isn't worth much without answering how and why.